# WinAppDriver not working with side loaded Universal Application

Tags: winappdriver

I am unable to load a side loaded Windows Universal application using WinAppDriver

I have verified my code works if I try to load the Windows Calculator application but I am unable to load my target application. I get an error message "The system cannot find the file specified". I used the Get-AppxPackage method in PowerShell to get the application information for my target application. The method returned the data structure below:

Name              : AACE4B69.MazikAXCashier

Publisher         : CN=XXXXXXXXXXX

Architecture      : Neutral

ResourceId        :

Version           : 2.4.1.9

PackageFullName   : AACE4B69.MazikAXCashier_2.4.1.9_neutral__gfhc11b3bvd9y

InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\AACE4B69.MazikAXCashier_2.4.1.9_neutral__gfhc11b3bvd9y

IsFramework       : False

PackageFamilyName : AACE4B69.MazikAXCashier_gfhc11b3bvd9y

PublisherId       : gfhc11b3bvd9y

IsResourcePackage : False

IsBundle          : False

IsDevelopmentMode : False

NonRemovable      : False

Dependencies      : {Microsoft.WinJS.2.0_1.0.9600.17018_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe}

IsPartiallyStaged : False

SignatureKind     : Developer

Status            : Ok

I have tried to load the application using the following fields in the AppID field:

Name

PackageFullName

PackageFamilyName

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{

    protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> windowSession;

    public const String AppID = "AACE4B69.MazikAXCashier_2.4.1.9_neutral__gfhc11b3bvd9y";
    public const String driverURL = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {

        if (windowSession == null)
        {

            // Configure the application connection and load data
            AppiumOptions opt = new AppiumOptions();
            opt.AddAdditionalCapability("app", AppID);

            try
            {
                // Create the driver object
                windowSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(driverURL), opt);
                Assert.IsNotNull(windowSession);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to open application with error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }}
```

I would expect one of these names to be the required Application ID and result in the app loading. Instead I get the error message "The system cannot find the file specified".

This application is side loaded and I am wondering if there is something different about that. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out the trick. I needed to user the PackageFamilyName appended with a qualifier. In my case this came out to be

```
    public const String AppID = "AACE4B69.MazikAXCashier_gfhc11b3bvd9y!App";
```

I got this value via a two step process. I used the Powershell Get-appxPackage *Mazik* to get the PackageFamilyName as I previously did. I then appended "!App" to this string to get the required value. I determined the "!App" string based on another Powershell script I found in an online article. I used the following script to determine what the appended ID value was:

(Get-AppxPackageManifest  (Get-AppxPackage *Mazik*)).package.applications.application.id

This returned "App" and I constructed the final string as described above. It looks like the "!App" is the typical ending to the required AppID but I have to assume there are different values for different situations. Once I got the correct AppID value everything worked as expected and the side loaded application was not an issue

Answer (score 0):

The application key is usually a little shorter I believe. Are you sure you didn't make a mistake while copying it over to your code? Please double check app IDs for errors.
[image]

I created a shortcut to the Clocks app and then right clicked it. The "Target type" and "Target" fields contain the exact application key that work.

Comment: I believe I should be using the Name field value: AACE4B69.MazikAXCashier. I used that value also and it does not work either. As I said above I tried using the Name, PackageFullName and PackgeFamilyName as the AppID value and all three failed with the error "The system cannot find the file specified". It just so happens that the PackageFull name was the last field I tried and still showing in the code. Any suggestions for how to find an alternative AppID value. The issue must be a problem with my AppID or related to side loading the app but I can't find another AppID